# Runscope Error contacting host SSL

Tags: api, url, ssl, ssl-certificate, runscope

I am using Runscope only for a short time now however it seems pretty straight forward. I have had no problem with other APIs, however for this current one I am having problems.

The error I am getting is the following:

> Error contacting host SSL: certificate is valid for *.hostgator.com,
> hostgator.com, not NflArrest.com  To turn off SSL verification for
> this test, change your test's behavior settings, see
> https://www.runscope.com/docs/api-testing/behaviors for more details

From the documentation I read [here](https://www.runscope.com/docs/buckets#ssl-verification):

> SSL Certificate Verification
>
> By default, Runscope will only relay responses if the SSL certificate from the upstream API provider is valid and trusted. To bypass this protection (for instance if you're using a self-signed certificate) on a per-bucket basis, select  Bucket Settings in the left sidebar and deselect the option to 'Verify SSL Certificates'.

I have done that so to my knowledge it should work. However I still get the same error. The API documentation I am using can be found [here](http://nflarrest.com/api/).

Comment: Disable ssl verification in the Behaviors section of the Environment settings at the top of the test editor.

Comment: Thanks, can you create an answer and explain why doing it in the behaviour section instead of turning of SSL in the bucket settings? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Test's don't use the bucket setting, that's just for Gateway URLs/Traffic Inspector. To disable SSL verification in your test, expand the "Environment" section at the top of the test editor, select "Behaviors" and untoggle it there.

Comment: Unexpected the founder of Runscope would answer my question haha. That's cool.